# Crop impage within the colored box

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image as below. I need to detect the 'green' box & crop tat portion of the image as a separate image.

I can only use numpy & opencv

I looked at several posts, but i am not able to figure this out. Can anyone help.
Based on the searches, i am guessing that some-kind of mask needs to be used for this. If yes, please provide some info on how to select the values for a particular color. I have seen that color value selection is in itself a huge topic but i am not able to figure it out myself.  Any guidance i appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find all green pixels, find contours, and crop the bounding rectangle of the contour found:

- Gel all green pixels in the image, where RGB = (0, 255, 0):

  ```
  green_pix = np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), 2)
  ```
- Convert green_pix to `uint8` binary image with values 0 and 255:

  ```
  thresh_gray = green_pix.astype(np.uint8)*255
  ```
- Find contours in `thresh_gray`:

  ```
  contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  ```
- Get rectangle, and crop rectangle

  ```
  out = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
  ```

Here is a working code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# (cv_major_ver, cv_minor_ver, cv_subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')  # Get version of OpenCV

img = cv2.imread('green_box.png')

# Gel all green pixels in the image - where RGB = (0, 255, 0)
green_pix = np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Convert green_pix to uint8 binary image with values 0 and 255
thresh_gray = green_pix.astype(np.uint8)*255 

# Find contours in thresh_gray.
# if int(cv_major_ver) < 4:
#     _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# else:
#     contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # Shortcut (get index [-2] instead of using if-else).

# Get rectangle (assume there is only one contour)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

# Crop rectangle
out = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)  #Save out to file (for testing).

# Show result (for tesing).
cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

---

### Update:

I have a more simple solution:

- Find indices of green pixels.
- Get minimum and maximum index in both axes.
- Crop rectangle.

Here is the code:

```
# Find indices of green pixels.
idx = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 255, 0), 2))

# Get minimum and maximum index in both axes (top left corner and bottom right corner)
x0, y0, x1, y1 = idx[1].min(), idx[0].min(), idx[1].max(), idx[0].max()

# Crop rectangle
out = img[y0:y1+1, x0:x1+1, :]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. What if there are more than 1 green boxes? This does not seem to work. do i need to do something else then? Also, if the input image is a `jpg` instead of a `png`, does anything needs to be changed?

Comment: For multiple green boxes, you can iterate all contours that were found. In case there are few green pixels other then the box, you may need to filter the small contours (or erase them using morphological operation). For `jpg`, there is a chance that some of the green pixels are not going to be `(0, 255, 0)`, due to compression artifacts. You may need to look for pixels that are certain range like: red < 10 and green > 240 and blue < 10...